# JSTAT in Unix Script Not Working Properly

Tags: java, linux, unix, jstat

When writing a unix script, I am very confused why the script is erroring out.

The script is this...

```
jvmpid=$(pidof java)
./jstat -gc $jvmpid
```

When I run the script, it errors out:

> Malformed VM Identifier: 3492 Usage: jstat -help|-options
>          jstat - [-t] [-h]  [ []]
>
> Definitions:         An option reported by the -options option
>           Virtual Machine Identifier. A vmid takes the following
>   form:
>                        [@[:]]
>                   Where  is the local vm identifier for the target
>                   Java virtual machine, typically a process id;  is
>                   the name of the host running the target Java virtual machine;
>                   and  is the port number for the rmiregistry on the
>                   target host. See the jvmstat documentation for a more complete
>                   description of the Virtual Machine Identifier.          Number of samples between header lines.   
>   Sampling interval. The following forms are allowed:
>                       ["ms"|"s"]
>                   Where  is an integer and the suffix specifies the units as
>                   milliseconds("ms") or seconds("s"). The default units are "ms".          Number of samples to take before
>   terminating.   -J      Pass  directly to the runtime
>   system.

However, if I execute each line of the script inside the shell directly, every works fine.

Any clues? I've searched the web for help already.

Comment: ..it must be something with the formatting (quotes!?) of `$jvmpid` ...

Comment: ..I can reproduce this error message only with single quotes (on my win cmd)

Comment: `Malformed VM Identifier: '6604'`

Comment: @xerx593 What was your solution to fix this? Did you use double quotes? Around the entire $jvmpid or just around jvmpid?

Comment: actually I didn't have the issue, @menschm23, I just tried to reproduce yours....what happens when you try it manually!?? (combining these both commands in a shell)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and I sorted it out. The problem seems to be that the variable jvmpid does not have '3492' but '3492CRLF', so it is not correctly understood by jstat.
I have written a bash script that uses printf to format the variable correctly into a decimal. printf gives an error doing this, however does the job.

```
JAVAPID=$(pidof java)
#Transform the pid into a valid decimal as the output of pidof has some escape characters. Also avoid printing the printf error
JAVAPID1=$(printf "%d" $JAVAPID 2> error.txt)
#Remove the error file generated by printf. Gave an error but did the job
rm -f error.txt
#Execute the command
jstat -gc $JAVAPID1
```

As you can see I am not an expert in bash scripting, so this can probably be done in a cleaner way, but it is the best way that I found.
Hope it helps.